# Reiniciar aplicação em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop

Como reinicio meu programa com Python?

```
cpf = input('Digite os nove primeiros dígitos do CPF: ')

if len(cpf) != 9:
    # Aqui deve reniciar a aplicação.
```

Comment: O que você chama de reiniciar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se deseja voltar a pedir o dado seria assim:

```
while True: #inicia o laço
    cpf = input('Digite os nove primeiros dígitos do CPF: ')
    if len(cpf) == 9: #se está ok não precisa mais continuar o laço
        break
    #possivelmente mais código aqui
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gCIIqy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qcnxopwj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/Loop.py).

Essencialmente em aplicações console é assim que se faz. Claro que tem como abstrair pra não ficar repetitivo. Tem outras técnicas para entradas em conjunto.

Comment: que eu saiba diretamente não. Deve ter alguma biblioteca que permite isso. Como faria no .NET?

Comment: Essa segunda pergunta - "tem alguma forma de filtrar só digitos" - é MUITO diferente da primeira - melhor abrir outra questão.

Mas - não diretamente, você tem que programar ou usar uma biblioteca de User Interface - seja gráfica ou texto, para isso.

Answer (score 3):

Para reiniciar sua aplicação vc pode criar o seguinte método:

```
import sys
import os
def restart_program():
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
```

ai quando quiser reiniciar a aplicação vc chama:

```
restart_program()
```

Mais dependendo do problema vc pode fazer um simples laço de repetição por exemplo:

```
while True:
    cpf = input('Digite os nove primeiros dígitos do CPF: ')
    if len(cpf) == 9:
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Acredito que no seu caso trabalhar com o laço seria a melhor opção

Answer (score -1):

Realmente, o comentário acima está correto, mas se caso seja algo somente para chamar novamente a opção de digitar o CPF, pode usar a repetição (Assim como no comentário acima):

```
cpf = input('Digite os nove primeiros dígitos do CPF: ')
if len(cpf) != 9:
     break
     #Para a operação
else:
     continue
```

Comment: Se isso já foi dito na outra resposta, por quê respondeu também? Não consegui entender o que você agregou à resposta que não estava na outra.